# Release of mysql lock outside transaction (rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

We have been seeing a lot of errors recently:

```
ActiveRecord::TransactionIsolationConflict: Transaction isolation conflict detected: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Not able to figure out the reasoning behind it. But noticed one thing in our code which is trying to lock a record outside transaction:

```
acc = Account.lock.find acc_id
```

Above code is not inside any transaction and is used just to check that the other transaction which also obtains the same lock is finished or not. Any thoughts on if this can be the culprit ?

Answer (score 2):

The InnoDB use row level locking for better concurrency when huge write load. Engine takes some precautions to get rid of phantom reads, one of these is gap_lock, which may be causing this problem. Use

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

to analyze about  gap_lock.

If this is proble, you can try following options

1. Change the `ISOLATION` level to `READ COMMITTED`.
2. `set innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1`. This will disables the gap locks except for foreign-key constraint checking or duplicate-key checking.
3. Use `show innodb status` again to analyse what is going on. If required optimise your code to avoid locking
4. If above does not work, try to increase lock_wait_timeout globally

`SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120`;

Or for a session

```
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120;
```

5. Check your config again, if still not updated then set again global variables

   ```
   show variables like '%wait_timeout%';

   show variables like '%tx_isolation%';

   SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check what is being configured on your MySQL server for `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` and `lock_wait_timeout`.
You can do this by running the following command

`show global variables like '%lock_wait_timeout';`

Which of those parameters is in use depends on your version of MySQL and the engine of the table

from the documentation:

> # select * from accounts where id=1 for update
>
> `Account.lock.find(1)`

`for update` means - acquire a lock for write.

Probably your transaction takes more time than configured on your DB, and the checking request that tries to verify the original transaction was finished - getting this error as the time for waiting runs out.